# Overlapping divs that follow their main container

Tags: html, css, countdown

I've made a container that display a countdown to the next subscription date for our subscribers, however there are some problems with the layout, whenever there are no `days`, `months` or `years` left, that specific box will be removed from the container with our `<xsl-if>` statement (this is not present in the fiddle, must delete timebox manually to test).

**SEE EDIT AT BOTTOM**

When one is removed, the main container gets smaller in width, and its important that the graphical elements inside, such as `.reflection` and `.reflectionLng` follows the same behavior and adjust themselves, I have some jQuery in place to take care of this, however I noticed that it still didn't function when "Days" were gone or removed, even though it works as intended when "Years" and "Months" are gone.

> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Staehren/2xpLzh3p/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="timeContainer">
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxYears">
      <span class="timeNum">
            <xsl:text><int:text>7</int:text></xsl:text>
                        </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
                                    <xsl:text><int:text>YEARS</int:text></xsl:text>
                                </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxMonths">
      <span class="timeNum">
            <xsl:text><int:text>11</int:text></xsl:text>
                        </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
                                    <xsl:text><int:text>MONTHS</int:text></xsl:text>
                                </span>
    </div>
        <div class="timeBox">
      <span class="timeNum">
            <xsl:text><int:text>18</int:text></xsl:text>
                        </span>
      <br />
      <span class="timeChar">
                                    <xsl:text><int:text>DAYS</int:text></xsl:text>
                                </span>
      <div class="reflection"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="reflectionLng"></div>
  </div>
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the `.reflection` element being nested inside the `div` "Days" however I cannot pinpoint what the issue is.

Please help me make the container shown in the fiddle act as the screenshot below, when the `timeBox` for "DAYS" is not longer active or displayed.

[image]

**EDIT**: I updated the jsfiddle, fixed it so that the container now adjusts its width accordingly when "Days" `timeBox` is removed from the container, however the div `.reflection` is still nested inside of the "Days" `timeBox`, and I can't get it working properly outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's how I would do it. I would change the `<div>` elements that you were using to create the "background" to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. And instead of trying to alter the CSS with jQuery I would just alter the class of the `timeContainer` accordingly and add the appropriate CSS declarations.

Here's a snippet with all three values visible:

```js
 if ($('.timeContainer #timeBoxYears').length <= 0 && $('.timeContainer #timeBoxMonths').length <= 0) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('one-part');
 } else if ($('.timeContainer #timeBoxYears').length <= 0 || $('.timeContainer #timeBoxMonths').length <= 0 || $('.timeContainer #timeBoxDays').length <= 0) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('two-parts');
 } else {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('three-parts');
 }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
}
.timeBox {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
span.timeNum {
  font-size: 38px!important;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.timeChar {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.timeContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(#942949, #c83762);
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.35);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
  display: table;
}
.timeContainer::before {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer::after {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-26deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.one-part::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.one-part::after {
  transform: rotate(-63deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="timeContainer">
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxYears">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>7</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>YEARS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxMonths">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>11</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>MONTHS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxDays">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>18</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br />
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>DAYS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's a snippet with only two values visible:

```js
 if ($('.timeContainer #timeBoxYears').length <= 0 && $('.timeContainer #timeBoxMonths').length <= 0) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('one-part');
 } else if ($('.timeContainer #timeBoxYears').length <= 0 || $('.timeContainer #timeBoxMonths').length <= 0 || $('.timeContainer #timeBoxDays').length <= 0) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('two-parts');
 } else {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('three-parts');
 }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
}
.timeBox {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
span.timeNum {
  font-size: 38px!important;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.timeChar {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.timeContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(#942949, #c83762);
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.35);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
  display: table;
}
.timeContainer::before {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer::after {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-26deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.one-part::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.one-part::after {
  transform: rotate(-63deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="timeContainer">
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxMonths">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>11</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>MONTHS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxDays">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>18</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br />
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>DAYS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's a JSFiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/pfbuLhux/

**EDIT:**

Oops I didn't look closely at your jQuery. Now it's fixed and should work on any situation no matter which box is removed. Also I just set `display:none;` to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements when there's only one box, so they won't be displayed at all.

```js
 if ($(".timeContainer > div").length <= 1) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('one-part');
 } else if ($(".timeContainer > div").length <= 2) {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('two-parts');
 } else {
   $('.timeContainer').addClass('three-parts');
 }
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
}
.timeBox {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
span.timeNum {
  font-size: 38px!important;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 13px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.timeChar {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}
.timeContainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(#942949, #c83762);
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(186, 186, 186, 0.35);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
  display: table;
}
.timeContainer::before {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer::after {
  content: '';
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
}
.timeContainer.three-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::before {
  transform: rotate(-26deg);
}
.timeContainer.two-parts::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.timeContainer.one-part::before {
  display: none;
}
.timeContainer.one-part::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="timeContainer">
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxYears">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>7</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>YEARS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxMonths">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>11</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br/>
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>MONTHS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeBox" id="timeBoxDays">
      <span class="timeNum">
        <xsl:text><int:text>18</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
      <br />
      <span class="timeChar">
     <xsl:text><int:text>DAYS</int:text></xsl:text>
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

A new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/qdbyaaxb/

Comment: Very smooth solution, I like yours better, however when there's only `days` visible the graphic is different from when it's only `months` or `years` visible individually. Eitherway I'd like `reflectionLng` to be gone completely when it's only one `timeBox` being shown. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Once again, great answer, i'll mark it as answered now, thanks for the help thepio. If you feel you have time I think a good idea is to add a small edit snippet where you explain your code or how it works for future reference

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! I will add explanation to my answer as soon as I have time and I still remember to do it.